# Black color appears when moving origin to top when keyboard pops

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikeyboard

I am moving the origin of the `self.view` by the `-minY` of the text field when the keyboard shows to make the text field show at top of the screen. But if the text field is near the bottom, the frame bottom gets black color. I tapped on the first text field in the attached image which moves it to top. Is there a way to move the view without displaying black color?

The view hierarchy is

```
+ UIViewController
  + UIView
    + UIScrollView
      + UIView
        - UITextField
        - UITextField
        - UITextField
```

```
self.view.frame.origin.y = -(tagsTextField.frame.minY)
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by setting scrollview content offset on textfield tap.

```
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: tagsTextField.frame.minY), animated: true)
```

And resetting on keyboard dismiss.

```
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), animated: true)
```

Comment: Your question doesn't describe whether you are using view, scroll view or tablview...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background color of the embedding view (perhaps your navigation controller) the same color as your view background color.

What I usually do in form screen is I put my input fields in a `UITableView`. Then, instead of moving the view up to make the current input field visible, I scroll the `UITableView`.

So, the background view/color of the `UITableView` does not move.

Answer (score 0):

You can move frame up when keyboard frame hides your textfield by the height of keyboard:

```
override func keyboardWillBeShown(note: Notification) {
    let userInfo = note.userInfo
    let keyboardFrame = userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! CGRect
    if keyboardFrame.intersects(activeTextField.frame) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            self.view.frame.origin.y = -keyboardFrame.height
        }
    }
}

override func keyboardWillBeHidden(note: Notification) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
}
```